# Error while training the model, showing 'Inconsistent number of samples'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp

Below is the piece of code which is probably causing the problem->

```py
gs_gnb.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

which is  a part of the code below

```py
#Model Creation

#GaussianNB

pipe_gnb = Pipeline([
    ('vect', TfidfVectorizer()),
    ('to_dense', DenseTransformer()),
    ('gnb', GaussianNB())
])

params_gnb = {
        'vect__ngram_range': [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3)],
        'vect__max_df': [0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0],
        'vect__min_df': [0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 1],
        'vect__max_features': [3000, 4000, 5000, None],
        'vect__binary': [True, False],
        'vect__sublinear_tf': [True, False]
}

gs_gnb = GridSearchCV(pipe_gnb, params_gnb, verbose=10, cv=5, n_jobs=-1, scoring='f1', error_score='raise')
gs_gnb.fit(X_train, y_train)

print('Best accuracy: ', gs_gnb.best_score_, end='\n')
print('Params: ', gs_gnb.best_params_)
```

The shapes of X_cbe, y, X_train, y_train is as follows

(7613, 3) (7613,) (5329, 3) (5329,)

the splitting code->

```py
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_cbe, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
```

(X_cbe is basically CategoryEncoded part of X, hence, has the same dimensions)

the error message->

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
_RemoteTraceback                          Traceback (most recent call last)
_RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mist/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 436, in _process_worker
    r = call_item()
  File "/home/mist/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 288, in __call__
    return self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/mist/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 595, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mist/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 263, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mist/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 263, in <listcomp>
    return [func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mist/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/parallel.py", line 123, in __call__
    return self.function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mist/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 686, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "/home/mist/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 405, in fit
    self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params_last_step)
  File "/home/mist/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py", line 267, in fit
    return self._partial_fit(
  File "/home/mist/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py", line 428, in _partial_fit
    X, y = self._validate_data(X, y, reset=first_call)
  File "/home/mist/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 565, in _validate_data
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
  File "/home/mist/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 1124, in check_X_y
    check_consistent_length(X, y)
  File "/home/mist/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 397, in check_consistent_length
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [3, 4263]
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[130], line 25
     22 print(X.shape, y.shape, X_train.shape, y_train.shape)
     24 gs_gnb = GridSearchCV(pipe_gnb, params_gnb, verbose=10, cv=5, n_jobs=-1, scoring='f1', error_score='raise')
---> 25 gs_gnb.fit(X_train, y_train)
     27 print('Best accuracy: ', gs_gnb.best_score_, end='\n')
     28 print('Params: ', gs_gnb.best_params_)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py:874, in BaseSearchCV.fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    868     results = self._format_results(
    869         all_candidate_params, n_splits, all_out, all_more_results
    870     )
    872     return results
--> 874 self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
    876 # multimetric is determined here because in the case of a callable
    877 # self.scoring the return type is only known after calling
    878 first_test_score = all_out[0]["test_scores"]

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py:1388, in GridSearchCV._run_search(self, evaluate_candidates)
   1386 def _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates):
   1387     """Search all candidates in param_grid"""
-> 1388     evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py:821, in BaseSearchCV.fit.<locals>.evaluate_candidates(candidate_params, cv, more_results)
    813 if self.verbose > 0:
    814     print(
    815         "Fitting {0} folds for each of {1} candidates,"
    816         " totalling {2} fits".format(
    817             n_splits, n_candidates, n_candidates * n_splits
    818         )
    819     )
--> 821 out = parallel(
    822     delayed(_fit_and_score)(
    823         clone(base_estimator),
    824         X,
    825         y,
    826         train=train,
    827         test=test,
    828         parameters=parameters,
    829         split_progress=(split_idx, n_splits),
    830         candidate_progress=(cand_idx, n_candidates),
    831         **fit_and_score_kwargs,
    832     )
    833     for (cand_idx, parameters), (split_idx, (train, test)) in product(
    834         enumerate(candidate_params), enumerate(cv.split(X, y, groups))
    835     )
    836 )
    838 if len(out) < 1:
    839     raise ValueError(
    840         "No fits were performed. "
    841         "Was the CV iterator empty? "
    842         "Were there no candidates?"
    843     )

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/parallel.py:63, in Parallel.__call__(self, iterable)
     58 config = get_config()
     59 iterable_with_config = (
     60     (_with_config(delayed_func, config), args, kwargs)
     61     for delayed_func, args, kwargs in iterable
     62 )
---> 63 return super().__call__(iterable_with_config)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py:1061, in Parallel.__call__(self, iterable)
   1058     self._iterating = False
   1060 with self._backend.retrieval_context():
-> 1061     self.retrieve()
   1062 # Make sure that we get a last message telling us we are done
   1063 elapsed_time = time.time() - self._start_time

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py:938, in Parallel.retrieve(self)
    936 try:
    937     if getattr(self._backend, 'supports_timeout', False):
--> 938         self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
    939     else:
    940         self._output.extend(job.get())

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py:542, in LokyBackend.wrap_future_result(future, timeout)
    539 """Wrapper for Future.result to implement the same behaviour as
    540 AsyncResults.get from multiprocessing."""
    541 try:
--> 542     return future.result(timeout=timeout)
    543 except CfTimeoutError as e:
    544     raise TimeoutError from e

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py:458, in Future.result(self, timeout)
    456     raise CancelledError()
    457 elif self._state == FINISHED:
--> 458     return self.__get_result()
    459 else:
    460     raise TimeoutError()

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py:403, in Future.__get_result(self)
    401 if self._exception:
    402     try:
--> 403         raise self._exception
    404     finally:
    405         # Break a reference cycle with the exception in self._exception
    406         self = None

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [3, 4263]


What am I doing wrong?
```

Answer (score 0):

**First** of all, why do the shapes of `X` and `X_train` in terms of variables?
Why do you have 3 variables in the train set but 4 in the initial dataset?

> The shapes of X, y, X_train, y_train is as follows
> (7613, 4) (7613,) (5329, 3) (5329,)

**Next**, the error suggests that you need probably to reshape the `X_train` array so that you have `[samples, variables]`. If the `train_test_split`  was done correctly you should not see this error.

**Finally**, the `GaussianNB` classifier only works with dense data and does not support sparse matrices. `MultinomialNB`is perfect for text classification tasks with TF-IDF features as the ones you create. Here is a [nice article about this](https://towardsdatascience.com/text-classification-using-naive-bayes-theory-a-working-example-2ef4b7eb7d5a).

Here is an example using your code skeleton:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

# Toy data
X_train = [
    "I don't like this product",
    "The movie was great",
    "The movie was terrible",
    "This product is amazing",
    "I love this movie",
    "The product is terrible"
]

# 1 == positive sentiment, 0 == negative sentiment
y_train = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]

# Modeled
pipe_gnb = Pipeline([
    ('vect', TfidfVectorizer()),
    ('gnb', MultinomialNB())
])

params_gnb = {
    'vect__ngram_range': [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3)],
    'vect__max_df': [0.75, 1.0],
    'vect__min_df': [0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 1]
}

gs_gnb = GridSearchCV(pipe_gnb, params_gnb, verbose=10, cv=2, n_jobs=-1, scoring='f1', error_score='raise')
gs_gnb.fit(X_train, y_train)

print('Best F1 score:', gs_gnb.best_score_, end='\n')
print('Params:', gs_gnb.best_params_)
```

This prints:

> Best F1 score: 0.3333333333333333 Params: {'vect__max_df': 0.75,
> 'vect__min_df': 0.001, 'vect__ngram_range': (1, 1)}

Comment: Thank you for the answer @sealouk. Sorry what I actually meant was that the shape of X_cbe was 3 which I indeed used for the train test split as given in the code block. But still, I am getting the same error.

Comment: can you post the shape of `X_train, y_train` before calling `gs_gnb.fit(X_train, y_train)`?

Comment: Sure it's (5329, 3) (5329,) respectively.

Comment: can you post the full traceback and maybe some data to replicate this?

Comment: Sure. Link for dataset-> https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/nlp-getting-started/overview/description. I used the train.csv file.

Comment: Sorry but from full traceback you mean the full code?

Comment: the full error message

Comment: Also, how do you create `X_cbe`? post the full code

Comment: Sure. I edited the full error message in question above.

Comment: Here's the google collab link to the dull code-> https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1fk3jrCEmMP2k3ObicCVXYijKKOESmLKU

Comment: access denied. grant access or post full code here

Comment: Ohk sorry. I'll just update the link to the google collab code. That way it'll be easy for you.

Comment: Here's the updated link-> https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11WugbCWaYGRMa8dsjM7XcvCdJXAYDJEp?usp=sharing (with access).

Comment: Hi @seralouk just checking in to see if the error has been resolved. Thank you for helping this far but still I couldn't get it resolved myself. Do tell me if the error is fixed.

Comment: you are passing the entire DataFrame to the TfidfVectorizer, which is causing the issue. TfidfVectorizer expects a 1D array-like object of text documents (e.g., a list of strings) as input. You need to extract the relevant text column from your DataFrame and pass that to the TfidfVectorizer.

Comment: HI thnx for the response but I bneed all the three columns namely (itr_imputer__remainder__location remainder__impute__keyword remainder__remainder__text) to be passed into the pipelines since all theses three will be needed for the training of the model. Please help me with that.

Comment: Hi @seralouk just checking in for help. If you found any leads please do convey.